# JavaScript calling functions in another file

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I am aware of import and export, but this doesn't work here because each time you call imported function it starts a new instance of the original file from which it was exported.

I have a JavaScript Code A running in node.js continously without restarting. As it runs, it creates its own data and stores it in arrays.

Please how do I call a function within code A from another file which will run in the same instance Code A is currently running in and that **it will respect the stored data in arrays Code A has**?

If I use import/export, it calls a function from within Code A, but it doesn't have any stored data in arrays that I gathered whilst running Code A.

Thank you very much.

EDIT: Adding sample code

1. MAIN FILE

```
    let calculationArray = []
    
    function add(x, y) {

    if ( calculationArray.includes("abcde") ) {
    
    console.log("Calculation is on timeout", calculationArray)
    
    } 
    
    else {
       calculationArray.push("abcde")
       console.log(x + y)
       return x + y;
    }
    }
      
    module.exports = { add }
    
    
    setInterval(add, 3000, 5, 5)
```

2. SECOND FILE WHICH CALLS FUNCTION FROM MAIN FILE and doesn't respect the fact that calculationArray in the original file already has "abcde". It simply starts it own fresh instance with empty array

```
    const f = require('./calculation.js');
      
      
    f.add(10, 5);
```

Comment: `because each time you call imported function it starts a new instance of the original file from which it was exported.` this is not true and therefore doesn't mean you cannot use import/export, it means you need to change your code. Please post actual code; what exactly are you exporting and how are you calling the function?

Comment: Hi chris, thanks for reaching out. I added sample code. Run the original file, wait until you get "Calculation is on timeout [ 'abcde' ]" message, then run the second file. Second file shouldn't start, because the calculation in the original file is on timeout (the array includes "abcde"). But it doesn't care and starts new instance with empty array.

Comment: You're not using ES6 module's `export` `import` but rather CommonJS `require` and `module.exports`... https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html

Comment: If you are running the first file, then run the second file in a new window, then no, it will not allow you to access the first instance's array. Each node instance has its own memory. These are scripts, not databases. They contain instructions for node.exe, they do not magically store information. What you need to do is not require the file but rather communicate with the first instance. You can use for instance [node-ipc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-ipc) to do that

Comment: Are you expecting `setInterval(add, 3000, 5, 5);` to run before `f.add(10, 5);`??? Or are you expecting that every place that imports a file should be the same instance of that file?

Comment: @ChrisG - node-ipc seems very confusing, but you might be onto something with the database. I am trying to use MySQL with node to see if that can do the trick.

Comment: @epascarello Yeah, the ```setInterval(add, 3000, 5, 5);``` is there to simply trigger "Calculation on timeout" - and therefore when I call f.add(10,5) from the second file, the calculation shouldn't happen, because an array includes "abcde", therefore it's on timeout. SO I guess I am expecting imports to be in the same instance.

Comment: Problem is that is not going to work. You are trying to create session where there is none.

Comment: Hey @ChrisG , do you wanna post an answer? Not sure what the rules are as in how lengthy it has to be so not sure if u wanna bother, but the point is your suggestion has helped me solve this issue. Even though it unfortunately wasn't a simple native JavaScript solution, but MySQL database seems to work like a charm at the moment - will see how it goes as it's being constantly used. I really appreciate it and thank you! I used https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/ , https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mysql_create_db.asp in case someone needs it

Comment: Thinking about it, however don't have time at the moment for much except: [please do not use, recommend or link to w3schools](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com) It's a Google trap full of bad information

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you exactly load and call your scripts... so I tried to make something I could reason about of — out of your code.

Using **ES6 modules** (which use `export` and `import` statements), say you have:

- `calculation.js` — which adds every second 5+5 to a *file-internal* array
- `other.js` — which imports `calculation.js` and returns the result of `add(100, 100)` *200*
- a *main* `index.js` which calls:

  - `calculations.js` the first time after 3500ms
  - `other.js` after 6500ms

Here are the files and than some explanation on what happens using **ES6 dynamic import()**:

<sub>calculation.js</sub>

```js
// calculation.js

const calculationArray = [];

const add = (x, y) => {
    const result = x + y;
    calculationArray.push(result);
    console.log(calculationArray.reduce((a, v) => a + v), 0);
    return result;
};

// add 5+5 every 1sec
setInterval(add, 1000, 5, 5);

export { add }
```

<sub>other.js</sub>

```js
// other.js

import { add } from "./calculation.js";
// export the result of 100 + 100
export default add(100, 100);
```

and finally:
<sub>index.js</sub>

```js
// index.js

const delayedImport_calculation = async () => {
    const { add } = await import("./calculation.js");
    add(10, 5);
};

const delayedImport_other = async () => {
    const { default: otherResult } = await import("./other.js");
    console.log(otherResult);
};

setTimeout(delayedImport_calculation, 3500);
setTimeout(delayedImport_other, 6500);
```

If you call the *main* script like: `$ node ./index.js` from the terminal, you should expect the following console logs:

0. (Nothing for 3500ms)
1. `15` after 3500ms since that's when `calculation.js` was first imported into `index.js` and called the function `add(10, 5);`
2. `25` (after 1sec)
3. `35` (also after 1sec since the interval inside `calculation.js`)
4. `235` since `other.js` was dynamically imported into `index.js` and added 100 to the array
5. `other: 200` 200 since `other.js` exports just the result of `add(100 + 100)`
6. `245`, `255`, `265`, etc... on intervals of 1sec — **all proving the point that the array values are updated as expected**.

as you can see above, the `.reduce()` on the `calculationArray` returns the expected added values in `console.log`

---

Another simpler example (which might be closer to what you have?) with only two files:

- `calculation.js` that:

  - every 1sec adds 5+5 to the array
  - exports a default `add()` function and a `getAddResult()` method
- `index.js` which imports both the default and the helper methods

  - logs every second the sun of the array values using `getAddResult()`
  - calls `add(1000, 1000)` after 5sec

<sub>calculation.js</sub>

```js
const calculationArray = [];

const getAddResult = () => calculationArray.reduce((a, v) => a + v, 0);

const add = (x, y) => {
    const result = x + y;
    calculationArray.push(result);
    return result;
};

// add 5+5 every 100ms
setInterval(add, 100, 5, 5);

export default add
export { getAddResult }
```

<sub>index.js</sub>

```js
import add, { getAddResult } from "./calculation.js";

setInterval(() => {
    console.log(getAddResult())
}, 1000);

setTimeout(() => {
    add(1000, 1000);
}, 5000);
```

the log this time would be approximately like:

- `90`, `180`, `280`, `370` (in intervals of 1sec)
- `2470`, (after ~5000ms) proving the point that the values in array are updated
- `2560`, `2660`, etc... (also in intervals of 1sec)

---

PS:

for the above to work you either need to use `"type": "module"` in `package.json`, or just name all your files extensions as `.mjs`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. 
So far that I tried it, unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work. The whole point is that the original file contains an array which if includes a specific value, in this example "abcde", the calculation triggered from the second file should NOT happen, because "abcde" is present in the array of the original file. The only reason for setInterval is to trigger one calculation in the original file and then just keep saying "Calculation on timeout" and that should also prevent second file from performing any calculations.

Comment: OP has two node processes and for some reason expects the second thread to have access to the first one's array. This won't work regardless of how stuff is imported/required/etc. OP needs to store the array externally to the script so both processes can access the same storage space.